# Retrieving all objects of a key using parse

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, xcode6

I have a global array called `groupConversation` that is populated in another `UIViewController`. At first the array is empty, but when the user clicks a button in another `UIViewController` it is populated. However, the `UITableViewController` appears before the other `UIViewController`. But when the button is clicked in the other `UIViewController` while also populating the array, it pops the user to the `UITableViewController` but the `UITableViewController` is empty, and I have no idea why? How can I get the `UITableViewController` to contain data?

```
import UIKit


class GroupChatTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()


    println()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return groupConversation.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let groupChatCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupChatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    groupChatCell.textLabel?.text=groupConversation[indexPath.row]

    return groupChatCell
}


}
```